# TypeError: unbound method decode() must be called with JSONDecoder instance as first argument (got PrintJson instance instead)

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

> TypeError: unbound method decode() must be called with JSONDecoder instance as first argument (got PrintJson instance instead)

I am getting this error when I try to parse python object into json.

Using following code:

```
import json
from json import JSONDecoder

class TestJson():
    name = None
    pass

printJson = PrintJson()
print printJson
print JSONDecoder.decode(printJson) // at this line, getting this error
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are calling the method on the JSONDecoder class, not on an instance of it. This would work:

```
from json import JSONDecoder()
JSONDecoder().decode('{}')
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.

But It's not working at my end. After following given instruction, getting below mentioned error:-

File "C:\Users\abc\test\json_test.py", line 69, in <module>
    JSONDecoder().decode(printJson)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Getting error:-
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jagdeep/test/json_test2.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(jd.decode(str(printJson)))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: if you have *another* problem, perhaps you should ask it in a separate question

Comment: Question & problem both are same. I tried as per previous suggestion. That is not working. So I send the error track.